# Having difficulties with my PHP registration script

Tags: php, mysql, registration

This script seems to get hung up when it hits the series of "if" statements checking the email and password length. If I remove these statements, it properly inserts the data into the db.

```
<?php 

ob_start();
session_start();

if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['confirmpassword'])) {

$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$password = md5(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
$confirmpassword = md5(strip_tags($_POST['confirmpassword']));

$errors = array();

if (strlen($email) < 6) {
    $errors[] = "Email too short.";
}
if (strlen($email) > 25) {
    $errors[] = "Email too long.";
}
if (strlen($password) < 2) {
    $errors[] = "Password too short.";
}
if (strlen($password) > 25) {
    $errors[] = "Password too short.";
}
if ($password !== $confirmpassword) {
    $errors[] = "Passwords do not match.";
}

if (count($errors) == 0) {
    // Include database config file then connect to database
    require('db_config.php');
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Database Connection Error");
    $database = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("No Database");

    // Create query
    $query = "INSERT INTO bah_register VALUES ('','$email','$password')";

    // Query database and 
    mysql_query($query);

    // Success message
    echo "Thanks for signing up!";

} else {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error . "<br />";
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: what is the error, we can't help you without an error

Comment: Is there a specific error that it's generating? What's not working properly?

Comment: What is the issue? Jut saying it won't work properly will get you down-voted and this thread will be closed. Explain more.

Comment: Can you post `bah_register` create table script?

Comment: btw...the question is not a question but a statement, because of this ad a .,! or nothing, and not a ?

Comment: Not a big issue, but the part where you are checking if the password length is greater than 25, you are saying it's too short if it fails that check instead of it is too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you are `md5`ing the password before you check the length.  This puts the password at 32 characters, which is greater than your limit and producing an error.

Comment: :) +1. Yeah, almost the same time

Comment: @Matt No problem.  There have been plenty of those those on my part.  lol~

Answer (score 5):

You are checking `strlen($password) > 25` and your password is `md5` hashsum which is longer than 25 symbols. You probably wanted to check original value of password

Answer (score 3):

i don't know what is wrong with your code, but for your email you might consider using something like this :

```
if(!preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email)){
    $errors[] = "Email is not valid.";
}
```

many emails are longer than 25 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The foreach with the error array can easly be replaced with following code
`echo implode('<br />', $errors);`

Proper email validation can be done with the [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function

The strip_tags function can have undesired effects on the password, probably parts of it will be deleted. Think of the following password: «<my>super!password»